# Total column in DataTable gets doubled value

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm pulling data from an SQL Server and in C# i'm adding a column Total with the sum of the rows. However, my column keeps getting doubled, the code i'm using is this:

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ad.Fill(ds);
        ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Total",typeof(int));

        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1] = "0";

            for (int j = 1; j < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; j++)
            {
               int Value = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1]);
               ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1] = Value + Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][j]);
            }
        }
```

An example of my result is this:

```
Products ColA ColB ColC Total
ProdA      5    2    0    14
ProdB      0    0    0    0
ProdC      2    2    3    14
ProdD      1    0    1    4
```

What am I doing wrong in the C# loop? Thank you

Comment: but have you notice ProdC is not that doubled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code reviews are kind of frown-upon around here. However, I think your problem is the second `for` loop. At the end of each row, you are summing the total column with itself. Maybe it should be:

`for (int j = 1; j < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; j++)`

Note the **-1** bit in the condition for ending the loop. Also, I guess you are leaving out the first column on purpose, otherwise it should start `j = 0`.

Comment: Good spotting, that was indeed the case